# <Spring Security6> After login(at "/"), css appears on the screen

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a trouble. please help me.

My config

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

  private final CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Order(0)
  @Bean
  SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeHttpRequests(registry -> registry
        .requestMatchers("/mypage").hasRole("USER")
        .requestMatchers("/messages").hasRole("MANAGER")
        .requestMatchers("/config").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated());

    http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

    http.logout(config -> config.logoutSuccessUrl("/"));

    http.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);

    return http.build();
  }

  @Order(1)
  @Bean
  SecurityFilterChain resource(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeHttpRequests(registry -> registry
        .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated());

    return http.build();
  }
```

login.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<div th:fragment="header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark ">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="text-light" href="#"><h4>Core Spring Security</h4></a>
      <ul class="nav justify-content-end align-items-center">
        <li sec:authorize="!isAnonymous()" class="nav-item">
          <div class="text-light" th:text="${#authentication.name}">
            The value of the "name" property of the authentication object should appear here.
          </div>
        </li>
        <li sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()" class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-light" th:href="@{/login}">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-light" href="/">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-light" th:href="@{/users}">Signup</a>
        </li>
        <li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-light" th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
</html>
```

[This is an error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aFJq.png)

I found that redirectUrl is css path but don't know why.

[This is a debugging screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9b8f.png)
(AbstractAuthenticationFilter-> successHandler.onAuthenticaionSucess
and the successHandler instance is SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler)

When combining the two settings, it works fine.
I heard that using `permitAll()` to static resource is alright
because the latest spring security doesn't access a `HttpSession`.

Is there a way that works well when using permitAll()
and separating the settings of static resources?

After logging in, I want to return to the page I was previously on. not css path.